# Headphones not recognized Windows 10

Tags: audio, headphones, windows-10-upgrade, windows-10, headphone-jack

I just upgraded to Windows 10 from Windows 8.1 and now my headphones are not working. I have an Alienware M14x with three jacks (mic / headset / headphones) and have tried all of them. The built-in speakers continue to play sounds, hence I'm sure the jacks are not recognized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > <strike>Hey so after a couple hours of experimenting I have gotten my
> >     headphones to work. What worked for me was **uninstalling the control
> >     software** for my laptop's jack hardware (in my case the Recon3D
> >     Control Center). Many sources I found recommended reinstalling the
> >     software or drivers but my headphones are working now without
> >     reinstalling anything. Hope this helps, and good luck!</strike>
>
> **Update:**
>
> So after [screwing with my sound settings to fix my bluetooth
>   speaker's
>   bass](https://superuser.com/questions/949529/bluetooth-speaker-no-bass-on-windows-10-not-showing-up-in-devices-and-printers/),
>   my headphones are once again not working. I don't think I directly
>   changed any settings for them. Any help is appreciated. I have a
>   Recon3Di inside my alienware m14x. Thanks a bunch!

**Another Update:** 
 Ok so it seems I was able to fix it again. The *mic in* ports still don't work but I'm gonna take what I can get, at least until some customer support is available. This time I reinstalled the driver for my Recon3Di *which is apparently completely different from the Recon3D (The 3Di is nowhere to be found on [Creative Technology Ltd.'s website.](http://us.creative.com/) Instead I found it on a [Dell drivers page.](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/Drivers/DriversDetails?driverId=4T7P8))* I didn't find any drivers for windows 10 so I just tried the one for windows 8.1. Directly after the install my pc was acting up and unable to find ANY audio related hardware. Upon a reboot all sound function is restored; sound plays from speakers when aux-out jack is empty, plays from headphone when they're plugged in. (my mic jacks are still not working but i'm satisfied for now.)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

I faced same problem when upgraded to Windows 10 and Updating the sound driver worked like a charm for me.

```
Right Click My Computers > 
Manage > 
Computer Management Window appears > 
System Tools > 
Device Manager > 
PCName (Select your PC) > 
Sound, Video and Game Controllers > 
Right Click Audio Manager (I have 'Realtek HD Audio') > 
Update Driver
```

After Updating Restart the PC and ENJOY!

Comment: To Simplify the first 5 steps: Windows sign + X --> Device manager

Answer (score 1):

This was an issue within the beta version of Windows 10 that I encountered as well. The best thing I could recommend is either wait until Microsoft fixes it or downgrade back to Windows 8.1 temporarily if the headphones are absolutely necessary.

You may also wish to see if your audio drivers are compatible with Windows 10, they might not be just yet.