# Bluetooth Speaker no bass on windows 10 / not showing up in Devices and Printers

Tags: audio, bluetooth, windows-10, device-manager, audio-output

I have a Bluetooth speaker that works without drivers on all platforms. However, when connected to my computer the speaker has no bass. It seems from similar questions that this can be resolved by disabling handheld calling under Device Properties >> Services accessed through Devices and Printers. However my speaker is not visible under Devices and Printers. It is visible under Device Manager >> Sound Devices, but Services cannot be accessed from properties through the Device Manager. Is there a way I can bass without using Devices and Printers, or is it possible to find my speaker under Devices and Printers?

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get bass working. It seems for my speakers, the bass is processed by the input as a part of the trebel speakers, even though it's handled by a different physical component. In any case, I was able to get some bass through my speakers by going to Control Panel >> Sound, selecting the bluetooth speakers, right clicking and selecting configure, and toggline the 'full range speaker' option. Hope this helps.